# can any one tell me what is the issue self signed certificate in certificate chain..?

Tags: node.js

1.UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1514:34) at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:375:28)
at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:936:8)
at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:708:12)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:14192) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14192) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise
rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: please tell me the error

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).